# Combine two tables data into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's maybe pretty easy but I can not figure it out. Basically I am converting C# linq query to sql query for reduce execution time. However I am not good at sql query so that something I find very difficult. Here is my two tables and its record

**HRMS_EodRecord**

```
SELECT EmployeeId,HRMS_EodReferenceFk,ActualAmount FROM HRMS_EodRecord
```

Resulting like this:

```
EmployeeId    HRMS_EodReferenceFk    ActualAmount
   101                 1                 1000
   101                 2                  999
   101                 3                    0
```

And another table

**HRMS_EodReference**

```
SELECT ID FROM HRMS_EodReference
```

Resulting like this:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

What I want to combine this two tables data and result like this

```
 EmployeeId    HRMS_EodReferenceFk    ActualAmount
   101                 1                 1000
   101                 2                  999
   101                 3                    0
   101                 4                    0 ----From HRMS_EodReference
   101                 5                    0 ----From HRMS_EodReference
```

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient info on how the EmployeeId is related in the 2 tables, but this is something to get you started:

```
SELECT  rec.EmployeeId              --> Insufficient info on relationship
        , ref.ID                    AS HRMS_EodReferenceFk
        , CASE WHEN rec.ActualAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rec.ActualAmount END
                                    AS ActualAmount
FROM    HRMS_EodReference           AS ref
        LEFT JOIN HRMS_EodRecord    AS rec ON rec.HRMS_EodReferenceFk = ref.ID;
```

Comment: well there is no relation of **EmployeeId** between two table but have relation between **HRMS_EodReferenceFk**  and  **ID**  considering as `HRMS_EodReference` as parent and `HRMS_EodRecord ` as child @lee

Comment: In that case, how do you obtain derive the content (101) of EmployeeId for HRMS_EodReference.Id of  4 and 5?

Comment: exactly that is the problem. I do not have **EmployeeId**  on HRMS_EodReference table. **EmployeeId** only exist on child table of HRMS_EodReference, i.e: HRMS_EodRecord    table which related to each other by  HRMS_EodReferenceFk as foreign key of HRMS_EodReference.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just solve this by change my table structure.

Comment: Do gimme a "like" if it was helpful. tnx

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for SQL "right join", ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp

The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all records from the right table (table2), and the matched records from the left table (table1). The result is NULL from the left side, when there is no match.

```
 SELECT HRMS_EodRecord.EmployeeId, HRMS_EodReference.ID, HRMS_EodRecord.ActualAmount FROM HRMS_EodRecord
 RIGHT JOIN HRMS_EodReference ON HRMS_EodRecord.HRMS_EodReferenceFk = HRMS_EodReference.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one employee id,

```
select 101 as EmployeeId,
       ref.ID as HRMS_EodReferenceFk
       coalesce(rec.ActualAmount, 0) as ActualAmount
from HRMS_EodReference ref left join
     HRMS_EodRecord rec 
     on rec.HRMS_EodReferenceFk = ref.ID;
```

Presumably, though, you want this for many employees at once.  In that case, generate the rows using a `cross join`, then use `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
select e.EmployeeId,
       ref.ID as HRMS_EodReferenceFk
       coalesce(rec.ActualAmount, 0) as ActualAmount
from (select distinct EmployeeId
      from HRMS_EodRecord
     ) cross join
     HRMS_EodReference ref left join
     HRMS_EodRecord rec 
     on rec.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId and
        rec.HRMS_EodReferenceFk = ref.ID;
```